# How do I continue adding to an array without .append()?

Tags: python

Long story short, I'm writing a program to decode messages hidden in audio files and I've come across a problem where I need to store an "extracted" ASCII letter in an array or string in order to print a complete message. My current code only gives me the very last letter in the "message".

```
def decode(sound):

  for sample in getSamples (sound):
      ampValue = getSampleValue (sample)
      asciiNum = ampValue % 128


      if asciiNum == 0:
        break

      asciiLet = chr (asciiNum)


  showInformation (asciiLet)
```

How do I get my code to show all the letters hidden in the masked audio? Also, I have to do this without importing any modules.

Comment: I don't see any arrays being modified here.

Comment: Why without `append()`? Another option would be to move `showInformation(asciiLet)` into the loop.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 because the "version" of Python I'm using (which is mandatory for this assignment) doesn't have the .append() command unfortunately.

Comment: It would take _significant_ effort to build an implementation of Python with a different `list` class. Are you sure it's not available, or is there a chance that you're just not using it properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
youre getting the last letter because it always replaced the  variable 'asciiLet' every loop. try to create an inital value then add it. 

def decode(sound):
  asciiLet = '' #<--- inital
  for sample in getSamples (sound):
      ampValue = getSampleValue (sample)
      asciiNum = ampValue % 128


      if asciiNum == 0:
        break

      asciiLet += chr (asciiNum)  #<--- add it 


  showInformation (asciiLet)
```

Comment: Yea, I figured that was the issue but this solution doesn't seem to help. Instead it infinitely loops and displays the last decoded letter.